# Is there a Java OutputStream filter that decompresses rather than compresses like GZipOutputStream?

Tags: java, gzip

Java's GZipOutputStream's docs say the following:

> This class implements a stream filter for writing compressed data in
>   the GZIP file format.

What I need, though, is a stream filter for writing **decompressed** data instead.

For example, there's both a `InflaterOutputStream`, which decompresses data in the `deflate` compression format, and `DeflaterOutputStream`, which does the opposite by compressing data in the `deflate` format.

I tried to write my own filter by using `GZipInputStream` internally, but that requires a lot of work and, I believe, even a new Thread to consume the data as it's being written without having to completely buffer the full data before decompressing, which I can't do for performance reasons.

The reason I can't wrap the `InputStream` instead of the `OutputStream` is that I have a chain of encodings where GZip may be just one of them (the others all have `OutputStreamFilter` implementations I can use), and the encodings must be performed in whatever order they come.

Comment: If anyone needs one, I [wrote one](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/renatoathaydes/rawhttp/master/rawhttp-core/src/main/java/rawhttp/core/body/encoding/GZipUncompressorOutputStream.java) but it doesn't really do it the "right" way: it just pipes gzipped content written to it into a `GZIPInputStream`... which can be used to read the un-gzipped contents... it then reads that, writing out to another stream.